# How to delete entry in SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried to make DeleteEvent(),but it doesn't work. where do i need to change the code?

This is an Android Studio java code.

```
public class DBStructure {enter code here
    public static final String DB_NAME =    "EVENTS_DB";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String EVENT_TALE_NAME = "eventstable";
    public static final String EVENT = "event";
        public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String MONTH = "month";
    public static final String YEAR = "year";

}
```

*And this my DeleteEvent()*

```
public void DeleteEvent(String event, String time, String date, String month, String year, SQLiteDatabase database){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.remove(DBStructure.EVENT);
    contentValues.remove(DBStructure.TIME);
    contentValues.remove(DBStructure.DATE);
    contentValues.remove(DBStructure.MONTH);
    contentValues.remove(DBStructure.YEAR);
    database.delete(DBStructure.EVENT_TALE_NAME, "?=? AND ?=?",
            new String[] {DBStructure.EVENT, event, DBStructure.TIME, time});
}
```

Comment: can u show the code of usage of DeleteEvent() ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ContentValues` to use the `delete()` method:

```
public void DeleteEvent(String event, String time, String date, String month, String year, SQLiteDatabase database){
    database.delete(
        DBStructure.EVENT_TALE_NAME, 
        DBStructure.EVENT + " = ? AND " + DBStructure.TIME + " = ? AND " + DBStructure.DATE + " = ? AND " + 
        DBStructure.MONTH + " = ? AND " + DBStructure.YEAR + " = ?",
        new String[] {event, time, date, month, year}
    );
}
```

In the 2nd argument you construct the WHERE clause and the 3d contains in the form of a string array the parameters which will replace the placeholders `?`.